# How do I find and replace characters in a string in stanza?

Tags: stanza

Let's say I have a string `val s = "_1.2V_ADC"`

The period is invalid for my use case so I need to replace it with another character, like `p` so the final string should be `"_1p2V_ADC"`

Is there any easy way to do that in Stanza?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace` function for this:

```
val s = replace("_1.2V_ADC", ".", "p")
```

It will replace all matches of the string `"."` with the string `"p"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need this function from the `core` package :

```
public defn replace (str:String, s1:String, s2:String) -> String
```

You example become `replace("_1.2V_ADC", ".", "p")`
That gives `_1p2V_ADC`